# In 12.04, does zenity crash on you too?

Tags: zenity

When I run `zenity  --list --title=111 --column=222 --column=333 ab cd ef gh` and select any line with a mouse (or keyboard) and then click on "Ok", I got:

```
$ zenity  --list --title=111 --column=222 --column=333 ab cd ef gh
ef
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I select any line with a mouse (or keyboard) and then hit return on my keyboard or double click on said line, I got:

```
$ zenity  --list --title=111 --column=222 --column=333 ab cd ef gh
ef
```

Is there something wrong with my computer, or does it happen on yours two? It used to work in 11.10. If it is not something my-computer-specific, I will report a bug, but this seems strange, I could not Google anyone with similar results and I believe zenity is widely used.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, seems to be this bug: http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zenity/+bug/968534